# FlagSet with C++ templates

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, bitset

I am creating a C++ header-only library for FlagSet.
 A FlagSet is a container for booleans with meaning. Usually, it is done with constants (macro, enums, whatever), for example :

```
//from SDL2
#define SDL_INIT_AUDIO          0x00000010u
#define SDL_INIT_VIDEO          0x00000020u
#define SDL_INIT_EVENTS         0X00000040u
...
Uint32 flags = SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO;
if ((flags & SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) {
    /* video implies events */
    flags |= SDL_INIT_EVENTS;
}
```

It is not as safe as a scoped enum (`enum class`), you can mix up flags from one meaning to another (for example, it is possible to do `SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` even if they do not share any logic).

The aim of my FlagSet library is to provide a "scoped flags" (by analogy with scoped enum). Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

/////////// INDEX OF ///////////

template<typename S,typename...>
struct IndexOf_t {};

template<typename S, typename...Ts>
struct IndexOf_t<S,S,Ts...> {
    static constexpr std::size_t index = 0;
};

template<typename S, typename T, typename...Ts>
struct IndexOf_t<S,T,Ts...> {
    static constexpr std::size_t index = 1 + IndexOf_t<S,Ts...>::index;
};

template<typename Searching, typename...List>
constexpr std::size_t IndexOf = IndexOf_t<Searching,List...>::index;

////////////////////////////////



/////////// FLAGSET ////////////

template <typename U, typename...Fs>
struct FlagSet {
    using underlying_t = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<U>,U>;

    constexpr FlagSet() : mData{0} {};

    template<typename...Ts>
    static constexpr FlagSet<U,Fs...> Value() {
        return FlagSet { Mask<Ts...> };
    };

    template<typename...Ts>
    constexpr void set() {
        mData |= Mask<Ts...>;
    };

    template<typename...Ts>
    constexpr void reset() {
        mData &= ~Mask<Ts...>;
    };

    template<typename...Ts>
    constexpr void toggle() {
        mData ^= Mask<Ts...>;
    };

    constexpr void setAll() {
        set<Fs...>();
    };

    constexpr void resetAll() {
        reset<Fs...>();
    };

    constexpr void toggleAll() {
        toggle<Fs...>();
    };


    template<typename...Ts>
    constexpr bool anyOf() const {
        return (mData & Mask<Ts...>) != 0;
    };
    template<typename...Ts>
    constexpr bool allOf() const {
        return (mData & Mask<Ts...>) == Mask<Ts...>;
    };
    template<typename...Ts>
    constexpr bool noneOf() const {
        return (mData & Mask<Ts...>) == 0;
    };

    constexpr bool all() const { return allOf<Fs...>(); };
    constexpr bool any() const { return anyOf<Fs...>(); };
    constexpr bool none() const { return noneOf<Fs...>(); };


    std::string to_string(char zero = '0', char one = '1') const {
        std::string str(sizeof...(Fs),zero);
        std::size_t count = 0;
        for (U data = mData; data != 0 && count < sizeof...(Fs); data >>= 1, ++count)
            if (data & 1) str[count] = one;
        return str;
    }

    template<typename U_, typename...Fs_>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, FlagSet<U_,Fs_...> fs);

private:

    U mData;

    constexpr FlagSet(U data) : mData{data} {};

    template<typename...>
    struct Mask_t { 
        static constexpr U mask = 0;
    };
    template<typename T>
    struct Mask_t<T> {
        static constexpr U mask = 1 << IndexOf<T,Fs...>;
    };
    template<typename T, typename...Ts>
    struct Mask_t<T,Ts...> {
        static constexpr U mask = Mask_t<T>::mask | Mask_t<Ts...>::mask;
    };

    template<typename...Ts>
    static constexpr U Mask = Mask_t<Ts...>::mask;


};

template<typename U, typename...Fs>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, FlagSet<U,Fs...> fs) {
    return os << fs.to_string();
};


////////////////////////////////

namespace Direction {
    struct UP;
    struct DOWN;
    struct LEFT;
    struct RIGHT;
    using Type = FlagSet<char, UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT>;
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    Direction::Type player_dir = Direction::Type::Value<Direction::DOWN>();

    cout << "display : UP DOWN LEFT RIGHT " << endl;
    cout << "player1 : " << player_dir << endl; // 0100
    player_dir.set<Direction::LEFT>(); //now the player goes left too
    cout << "player2 : " << player_dir << endl; // 0110
    player_dir.resetAll(); //now the player goes nowhere
    cout << "player3 : " << player_dir << endl; // 0000
    player_dir.set<Direction::RIGHT>(); //now the player goes right
    cout << "player4 : " << player_dir << endl; // 0001
    player_dir.toggle<Direction::RIGHT,Direction::UP>(); //now the player goes only up
    cout << "player5 : " << player_dir << endl; // 1000

    if (player_dir.any()) //player is moving
        cout << "player is moving !\n"; //TRUE
    if (player_dir.noneOf<Direction::LEFT,Direction::RIGHT>()) //player is not moving on x-axis
        cout << "player not moving on x-axis\n"; //TRUE
    if (player_dir.noneOf<Direction::UP,Direction::DOWN>()) //player is not moving on y-axis
        cout << "player not moving on y-axis\n"; //FALSE
    return 0;
};
```

Thank you for anyone reviewing my code !

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://gist.github.com/makulik/7963331

Comment: This might also be interesting: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183246/type-safe-flag-sets-bit-fields-that-make-sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a great idea to provide a type-safe bit-mask, I like your idea a lot. That said, I feel like your code is in great need of modernization and simplification.

Recursion through inheritance is now a testimony to the ingenuity of our great predecessors, but it's time to get acquainted with `if constexpr` and `fold expressions`. I agree that you'll need C++17, but it's 2018 after all. For instance, here's your `index_of` as a two-liner:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t index_of() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, U>) return 0;
    else return 1 + index_of<T, Ts...>(); // doesn't have to be well-formed if U == V
}
```

N.B: As a function qualifier, `constexpr` means that, given compile-time arguments, the function will be executed at compile-time.

In the same spirit, you can simplify `Mask`:

```
template <typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Flag_set {
    // ...
    template <typename... Us>
    constexpr std::size_t mask() {
        return ((1 << index_of<Us, Ts...>()) | ...); // fold expression
    }
    // ...
    U flags;
};
```

`((1 << index_of<Us, Ts...>()) | ...)` will be expanded as:

```
  (1 << index_of<Us1, Ts...>())
| (1 << index_of<Us2, Ts...>())  
| ...                           
| (1 << index_of<UsN, Ts...>()))
```

Yet another function you can simplify, `to_string()`:

```
template <typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Flag_set {
    // ... 
    std::string to_string() {
        std::string result;
        (result.push_back(mask<Ts>() & flags ? '1' : '0'), ...); // fold
        std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
        return result;
    }
    // ...
    U flags;
};
```

Here, the fold expression is expanded around the comma operator:

```
result.push_back(mask<Ts1>() & flags ? '1' : '0'),
result.push_back(mask<Ts2>() & flags ? '1' : '0'),
...
result.push_back(mask<TsN>() & flags ? '1' : '0');
```

Here's a minimal working example you can toy with and enhance with static assertions and such:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t index_of() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, U>) return 0;
    else return 1 + index_of<T, Ts...>();
}

template <typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Flag_set {

    Flag_set() : flags(0) {}

    template <typename... Us>
    constexpr std::size_t mask() {
        return ((1 << index_of<Us, Ts...>()) | ...);
    }

    template <typename... Us>
    constexpr void set() {
        flags |= mask<Us...>();
    }

    std::string to_string() {
        std::string result;
        (result.push_back(mask<Ts>() & flags ? '1' : '0'), ...);
        std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
        return result;
    }

    U flags;
};

int main() {
    Flag_set<std::size_t, char, int, float, double> fs;
    std::cout << fs.mask<char, float>() << '\n';
    fs.set<int, double>();
    std::cout << fs.to_string() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I don't fear C++17, indeed I want to master it, so your answer is really helping me ! I heard about fold expressions but I don't really get it, so thanks for providing me a minimal working example ! `if constexpr` is really something I will use.

Answer (score 10):

`IndexOf` can probably be a nested type of `FlagSet`, unless you intend for that to be part of the public interface.

```
using underlying_t = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<U>,U>;
```

Are you sure SFINAE is what you want to do here? It would probably make more sense to `static_assert` that `U` is integral.

At the same time, you might also want to static assert that `U` is unsigned, because you're doing bit twiddling, which is a dodgy prospect with signed types.

And also at the same time, you could static assert that `sizeof...(Fs)` is less than or equal to the number of bits in `U`.

Even better, perhaps, would be to static assert that `U` is an unsigned, possibly fundamental, integral type *or* a `std::bitset` or something else with the bit-twiddling interface you need.

Most every function could also probably benefit from being `noexcept`.

```
template<typename U_, typename...Fs_>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, FlagSet<U_,Fs_...> fs);
```

This doesn't really need to be a friend, because it's only using the public interface.

What I would suggest, though, is a function that writes the string form of the flag set into a buffer. Something like:

```
template <typename CharT>
constexpr auto write(CharT* buffer, std::size_t size, CharT zero = CharT('0'), CharT one = CharT('1')) noexcept
{
    // write zero and one into buffer[0] through
    // buffer[min(size, sizeof...(Fs)], basically as you do in to_string
}
```

With that function, you could implement both `to_string()` and the insertion operator:

```
auto to_string(char zero = '0', char one = '1') const
{
    auto s = std::string(sizeof...(fs), zero);
    write(s.data(), s.size(), zero, one);
    return s;
}

template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename U, typename... Fs>
auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& o, FlagSet<U, Fs...> fs) ->
    std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
{
    auto buf = std::array<CharT, sizeof...(Fs)>{};
    write(buf.data(), buf.size());
    o.write(buf.data(), buf.size());
    return o;
}
```

And you'll even get support for streams of other character types, too.

The only other thing I can think off of the top of my head is that you'll probably want `operator==` and `!=`. And maybe a way to set the flag set from either a bag o' bits (like an unsigned type or `std::bitset`) or by reading a string (as in, the complement of `operator<<`). Because otherwise, setting the flags using data read from a config file (for example) would be a pain.

Comment: Would be great to stress on importance of using `static_assert` here, as it is detrimental for useful error messages. +1 anyway, though.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, static_assert is something I will use ! For the `write` function, why not even if I don't like the `(raw pointer, size)` pattern (I consider using GSL::span ?). Using `operator<<` would be great, as you say for serialization it would be useful.